# Spring Data JPA query on a many-to-many relationship is returning all records instead of matching records

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "app_user")
public class AppUser implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "app_user_app_role",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "app_role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<AppRole> roles;
    
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "app_role")
public class AppRole implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "app_role_name")
    private String roleName;
}
```

The join table `app_user_app_role` has three columns: "id", "app_user_id", and "app_role_id", the last two of which are foreign keys to the corresponding tables.

I have the following JpaRepository method:

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Integer> {
    /**
     * Get a list of usernames for users with the specified role name assigned.
     * @param roleName
     * @return 
     */
    @Query("SELECT au.username FROM AppUser au \n" +
        "INNER JOIN AppRole ar \n" +
        "WHERE ar.roleName = :roleName")
    List<String> getAppUsersWithRole(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
}
```

I have three users, "johndoe", "sam", and "janegoodall". I have two roles, "User Admin" and "Test". "johndoe" and "sam" both have the "User Admin" roles, and "sam" has the "Test" role. "janegoodall" has no roles.

When I call `AppUserRepository.getAppUsersWithRole("User Admin")`, I get all three users' usernames rather than "johndoe" and "sam". When I call `AppUserRepository.getAppUsersWithRole("Test")`, I also get all three users' usernames rather than just "sam". When I call `AppUserRepository.getAppUsersWithRole("nonexistent role")`, I get an empty list as expected.

When I retrieve the individual user records and check their AppRole list they all have the expected roles, so I know the `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` in AppUser are set up correctly.

Why is my jpql query returning all usernames instead of the usernames of the users who have roles matching the `:roleName` parameter? (And why does it return no usernames when the role doesn't exist?)

Comment: why is there `\n` in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are not specifying the relationship between the `AppUser` and `AppRole` entities in your `INNER JOIN` statement. You should be using the `roles` field in the `AppUser` entity to establish it:

```
@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Integer> {
    /**
     * Get a list of usernames for users with the specified role name assigned.
     * @param roleName
     * @return 
     */
    @Query("SELECT au.username FROM AppUser au " +
        "INNER JOIN au.roles ar " +
        "WHERE ar.roleName = :roleName")
    List<String> getAppUsersWithRole(@Param("roleName") String roleName);
}
```

If the role doesn't exist then no rows are returned because `ar.roleName = :roleName` will never be true.

Comment: This does solve my problem, but I feel like I only halfway understand why. What was happening when I joined on `AppRole ar` instead of `au.roles ar`?